# How to use ajax auto complete to display values from a MySQL database when user types a letter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database

I am having problem with displaying the data from MySQL. I want that when I type a letter in the input field the values coming from the database will display the related values.

For example I type <kbd>A</kbd>, and it will show all the vales relating to that product. Below is my code - please provide your suggestions.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var hxmlhttp = false;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                //for newer browser except ie6
                xmlhttp  = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{
                //for ie6 and below
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObjectt("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            function askGoogleSuggest(){
                var input = document.getElementById("textField");
                if(input.value){
                    getData("select.php?qu=" + input.value,"targetDiv");
                }else{
                    var targetDiv = document.getElementById("targetDiv");
                    targetDiv.innerHTML = "<div></div>";
                }
            }
            function getData(dataSource, divId){
                if(xmlhttp){
                    var obj = document.getElementById(divId);
                    xmlhttp.open("GET",dataSource,true);

                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                            obj.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.send(null);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
        <h2>Langpayan Trademark</h2>
        <form >
            Search for <input type="text" id="textField"
                name="textField" onkeyup = "askGoogleSuggest()">
        </form>

        <div id="targetDiv">
            <p>it will display values</p>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

select.php

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','black98765','activity_8a')
        OR die("Cannot connect to MySql: ". mysqli_connect_error());
$display = "SELECT bug.* , product.*, hardware.hardware_brand, software.software_name, solution.solution_name, bug_hardware.*
        FROM bug 
        JOIN product ON bug.product_no = product.product_no
        JOIN bug_hardware ON bug.bug_no = bug_hardware.bug_no
        JOIN hardware ON hardware.hardware_no = bug_hardware.hardware_no
        JOIN software ON software.software_no = bug_hardware.software_no
        JOIN solution ON solution.bug_no = bug.bug_no
        WHERE product_name like '%on%'";
$re = mysqli_query($dbc, $display);
if($re){
    echo "<table border=1 id='table_form'>
        <tr>
        <th>Product Name </th>
        <th>Name of Bug </th>
        <th>Brand Name</th>
        <th>Operating System</th>
        <th>Solution</th>
        <tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($re)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['product_name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['bug_name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['hardware_brand']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['software_name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['solution_name']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";
}else{
    echo "Cannot fetch data";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your question? Does the code you posted not work? FWIW, unless you have a use case where you are not able to use jQuery, you might want to look into jQuery and jQuery UI Autocomplete, which does exactly what you are asking with minimal coding effort.

Comment: @mituw16 Yes the code seems not working it will not display suggestion when i type a word on the input field..I am not that familiar using jquery. Can you give me sample code?

Comment: Google is your friend here. There are tons of tutorials out there for jQuery and jQuery UI Autocomplete

Comment: Just a hint: since checking a database is quite expensive, i would recommend to use oninput instead of onkeyup, because onkeyup get's triggered every time you press ANY key while the input element is focused while oninput only get's triggered, when the value of the input element get's changed

Comment: @mituw yeah thanks so much but the requirement is to use ajax. Can you please check my code and give suggestion what do i need or add to my code?Thanks again

Comment: @Markai that is an inaccurate description of `oninput` ...throttling requests would be a better suggestion

Comment: @charlietfl where am I wrong? Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput or http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp or where you want. "The input event is raised when an <input> element value changes. "

Comment: @Markai but it kets changed on `keyup` also, so no benefit to switching events

Comment: @charlietfl if you press the left arrow key (for example), the value doesn't get changed but onkeyup get's triggered, while oninput does not get triggerd => benefit because you don't need to pull data again if the value doesn't get changed

Comment: Do you think there is something wrong with my select statement in select.php? I want to display the values inside the targetDiv but i cannot figure it out what's wrong with my code..Please help guys.

Comment: @markai oh yeah. Now i change the code but still it seems not working.i Updated the code.

Comment: @JayGorio Correct me when I am wrong, but you don't pass the `id` parameter to your `getData` function in which you try to write the data to an element. So changing the call of `getData` to `getData("select.php?qu=" + input.value, "targetDiv");` might solve the problem

Comment: @JayGorio What do you mean by "not working"? Is nothing shown in the element, are you not getting a response from the server or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73779/discussion-between-markai-and-jay-gorio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got solved in a dialogue:

The function `getData` missed the `divId` parameter when called inside the `askGoogleSuggest` function.

Also the line `WHERE product_name like '%on%'";` had to be changed to `WHERE product_name like '".$_GET['qu']."%'";` to behave as expected by OP